# What do the +-numbers at LHS of my question mean?

Tags: support

To this my former question you requested that I should send screenshots. Here are three:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Comment: You're asking about the 0, -1, -1, 0, and 4?

Comment: yes. --- Regards

Answer (score 2):

Those 0, -1, -1, 0, and 4 numbers next to your questions in that screenshot are the current scores for those questions: the upvotes minus the downvotes.

[Voting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) is a central feature of the Stack Exchange system; users with the upvote and downvote [privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) help sort good content above lower quality content so that the best answers to each question become apparent.

If you haven't yet, you'll want to take our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an overview of Stack Exchange's model and then browse the sections of our [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about asking, answering, voting, and more!

Comment: Thanks. But the terms "upvote" and "downvote" are not contained in the intetnet dictionary English/German. Regards.

Comment: Sorry about that! How about "vote up" or "vote down"? That's the result from clicking one of the gray triangles next to a post's score. The top one points upwards (click it for an upvote); the one below the score points downwards and is for a downvote.